# Reading a .xls file into a DataFrame using read_html creating a list, not a df

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

At first I tried reading the .xls file like this:

`df = pd.read_excel('/Users/KLG/regionlist1.xls')`

Which led to this error: `ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.`

Then I tried this after reading the `read_excel` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

`df = pd.read_excel('/Users/KLG/regionlist1.xls', engine='xlrd')`

Which led to this error: `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<table c'`

When opening the file in a text editor, I realized that the file is not actually corrupted, but rather html stored in an excel file somehow:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dg0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>Licensee Name</td><td>Program Number</td><td>Program Name</td><td>Program Address 1</td><td>Program Address 2</td><td>Town</td><td>Program Zip</td><td>Region</td><td>Description</td><td>Program Phone</td><td>License Expiration Date</td><td>License First Issue Date</td><td>License Number</td><td>Capacity</td><td>CCRR Name</td><td>CCRR Phone</td><td>Infant Capacity</td><td>Toddler Capacity</td><td>Preschool Capacity</td><td>Kindergarten Capacity</td><td>SchoolAge Capacity</td><td>Toddler and Preschool MixedGroup Capacity</td><td>Infant and Toddler MixedGroup Capacity</td><td>Kindergarten and SchoolAge MixedGroup Capacity</td><td>Preschool and SchoolAge MixedGroup Capacity</td><td>Limited School Age Capacity</td><td>Major Town Code</td><td>Program Type</td><td>WebSiteUrl</td>
</tr><tr>
```

`df = pd.read_html('/Users/KLG/regionlist1.xls')`

`df` is now a `list` object that looks like this (this also means that `df.head()` would throw an `AttributeError`):

[image: df]

Is this an issue with the encoding parameters for `read_html`? If it is, I don't know which encoding issue to use, or if this is an entirely different issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) always returns a list of dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Michael Delgado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888719/michael-delgado) mentioned that `pd.read_html` returns a list of data frames, I tried this and it worked for me:

```
df = pd.read_html('/Users/KLG/regionlist1.xls', header=0)

df[0].head()
```